# Superconductor inside an electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

If someone were to put a superconductor inside an electromagnet(where the iron or nail would normally be) how would the superconductor(ex. YBCO) behave? Would it be affected by the Meissner effect and just float inside the electromagnet, or would it be otherwise?

To rephrase my question, how would the movement of a superconductor be affected by the magnetic fields inside an electromagnet?